# Alternate colors with masked rows

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets, it seems that masking an odd number of rows in a range somehow defeats the alternate color formatting (adjacent rows will occur with identical colors). Is there a workaround using, e.g. conditional formatting instead?

Comment: With "masking a row", are you referring to _hiding_ a row?

Comment: Likely. I am using the French localization of Sheets which has the "Masquer" option in the local menu. The result is actually hiding the row!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could make a conditional formatting with the personalized formula option and put something like:

> =odd(row(A1))

You should replace A1 with the first cell of the range you're working with. Then every odd row will be applied the formatting you choose
If this doesn't help, share a sample spreadsheet ;)

Edit: just corrected the formula.i forgot the row part

Comment: This does not seem to work if some rows are hidden (I wrote "masked"), which was the meaning of my question. Hiding rows does not affect the numbering.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand before what you meant with masked. Later I'll try some little coding

Comment: `odd()` is not the right function to use in this context. You probably mean `isodd()`. That does not detect hidden rows though.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Isodd was the right option, and I didn't understand what he meant with masked, I thought that it was done kind of formatting like passwords that somehow interrupted the zebra format. Idiomatic things of two non English speakers!

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by using a helper column. Put this formula in cell `H1` (in *row 1*):

`=sequence(rows(A1:A))`

You can then format a range with zebra stripes with this conditional formatting custom formula rule:

`=isodd(subtotal(103, $H$1:$H1))`

In `$H$1:$H1`, you should replace the two instances of `1` with the row number of the first row in the range you are formatting.

Note that the helper *column* should not be be hidden, although *rows* within that column may get hidden per your preference. You can resize the helper column to a minimal width of `2` if it gets in the way.

Comment: Nice option, didn't know the use of subtotal! I'm guessing that the H column could be replaced with any column that would always have some value in it (would not be empty), right??

Comment: I meant that the helper column wouldn't be necessary if there is another column that's always non blank

Comment: The `isodd(subtotal())` formula requires a helper column. It is irrelevant whether the helper column is an existing column or a new column, as long all cells in the column are non-blank.

Comment: Great, it was for my own clarifying and for @jmichel if that spreadsheet already has a full column

Comment: My spreadsheet does have a full column, which I cas use a the helper column. It solved my problem.Great trick !

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)